# moment.js strict mode time format validation with time zone

Tags: javascript, validation, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to get moment.js to validate (strict mode) a user-entered date/time with time zone. Example:

```
moment("2018-01-20 06:30 PDT", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z", true).isValid();
```

This returns false, though the user-entered value is valid for my purposes. If I take off the time zone and the "Z" token it validates fine, as expected.

I've checked what seemed the most relevant SO posts but come up empty. I'd appreciate any tips. Do I need to use moment.tz in some form for this use case? Thanks much in advance.

EDIT: to clarify, "2018-01-20 06:30 PDT" is what the user enters manually, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z" is the (ISO 8601?) date/time format required by the app, and we massage those tokens to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z" to pass to moment.js for validation.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work instead of **PDT** you can provide timezone offset i.e **-0700** example -

```
moment("2018-01-20 06:30 -0700", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z", true).isValid();
```

For more details refer - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format